# How to put overflowed span inside a div

Tags: css, html

I need to put my span inside a div,but because the content of div is more, it is overflown out of the border of the parent div.
How to solve it?
My outer div should be flexible because the contents in span is dynamic.
Here is the plunker link = [DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/rjIru0HUgvpp59e1h7vH?p=preview)

```css
.outerDiv {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.div40 {
  width: 40%;
}
.div60 {
  width: 60%;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  <div class="outerDiv">
    <span class="div40">
      hello
    </span>
    <span class="div60">
      hello i am trying to insert this content inside the parent div,but i am not able to do so. My content should be inside the border of this div and i want the height not to be fixed as my content is dynamic.
    </span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you have defined `float: right` to your `div60` i.e. why this issue is occuring, all you need is to clear the `float` as: `.outerDiv::after, .outerDiv::before {  content: "";  display: table; } .outerDiv::after {  clear: both; }`

Comment: Add `overflow:auto;` in your outerDiv.

Comment: @KunJ Firstly, your solution to "Try" isn't fit for this purpose. Secondly, the solutions to be provided here needs to be concise, clear and helpful, not something to "Try".

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a new element after `div60`

```
<div class ="outerDiv">
  <span class = "div40">
    hello
  </span>
  <span class = "div60">
    hello i am trying to insert this content inside the parent div,but i am not able to do so. My content should be inside the border of this div and i want the height not to be fixed as my content is dynamic.
  </span>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

and add the following in your CSS

```
.clear {
    clear: both
}
```

Comment: Instead of adding a *DOM* you can refer him to go for **pseudo clearfix method** for clearing that `float`

Comment: Not sure about the browsers OP needs to support, adding a div is the safest.

Answer (score 0):

set the outerDiv to `display: inline-block`

```css
/* Styles go here */

.outerDiv
{
  width:100%;
  border:2px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}
.div40
{
  width:40%;
}
.div60
{
  width:60%;
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <div class ="outerDiv">
      <span class = "div40">
        hello
      </span>
      <span class = "div60">
        hello i am trying to insert this content inside the parent div,but i am not able to do so. My content should be inside the border of this div and i want the height not to be fixed as my content is dynamic.
      </span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By adding display inline block to outer div class you can achieve it.

```css
/* Styles go here */

.outerDiv
{
  width:100%;
  border:2px solid black;
  display:inline-block;
}
.div40
{
  width:40%;
}
.div60
{
  width:60%;
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <style>.outerDiv span{}</style></style>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <div class ="outerDiv">
      <span class = "div40">
        hello
      </span>
      <span class = "div60">
        hello i am trying to insert this content inside the parent div,but i am not able to do so. My content should be inside the border of this div and i want the height not to be fixed as my content is dynamic.
      </span>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move to fluid content... bootstrap.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        hello
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        hello i am trying to insert this content inside the parent div,but i am not able to do so. My content should be inside the border of this div and i want the height not to be fixed as my content is dynamic.
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://getbootstrap.com/assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
</html>
```